# How to test regex with visual studio?

Tags: regex

There way always question for me that is there any fast way to test Regular Expressions with Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to do this, we can just open a text file (`Ctrl + N`) and open the search box (`Ctrl + F`) and put the search method to `regex` ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8hOc.png)) just like [RegexR.com](http://regexr.com)

[image: Visual Studio]